# How to bind values to eventListeners in a react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in a situation where I am binding events to a another library in react, specifically fabric-js. The issue is that on the useEffect hook I'm unable to bind any value to the eventListener, and so I'm limited on the usage of the eventListener. Any idea how to solve ?

Comment: Give some code please, we can't help you if you don't give more informations